# Cambiar color del texto según valor en input

Tags: jquery

Necesito cambiar el color del del texto según el valor del `input`.

Lo estoy intentando pero el segundo color no me toma siempre prevalece el primero. Ahora lo estoy haciendo con `css` directo pero podría ser con un nombre de clase usando `.addClass` y `.removeClass`, ya lo probé de las dos formas y no lo logro.

Dejo la idea por favor Gracias.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    if (jQuery('.status').val() === "CANCELADO") {
        jQuery('.status').css("color", "green");
    }

    if (jQuery('.status').val() === "PENDIENTE") {
        jQuery('.status').css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="status" type="text" value="PENDIENTE" />
```

El `value` es un valor dinámico puede ser **CANCELADO** O **PENDIENTE**, depende del valor cambiar el color.

Answer (score 0):

No estás muy lejos de lograrlo, en la comparación `if` te falta un `else`. Edité tu código para agregar la dependencia de `jQuery` y el `snippet` funciona cambiando manualmente el `value` del `input`.

Te dejo un ejemplo comentado en el código de `jQuery`. Opté por usar un `radio button` para hacer el ejemplo más ilustrativo.

```js
//Al hacer click en un estado
$('.estado').click(function(){
  //Capturo el valor del estado
  let estado =$('input:radio[name=estado]:checked').val();
  //Asigno el valor del estado al input
  $('.status').val(estado);
  //Capturo el valor del input
  let status = $('.status').val();
  //Comparo el valor para asignar el color correspondiente
  if (status == 'CANCELADO') {
    $('.status').css("color", "green");
  } else if (status == 'PENDIENTE') {
    $('.status').css("color", "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="estado1" name="estado" class="estado" value="CANCELADO">
<label for="estado1"> CANCELADO</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="estado2" name="estado" class="estado" value="PENDIENTE">
<label for="estado2"> PENDIENTE</label><br>
<input class="status" type="text" value="" />
```